# Prove that ln(n) < n for the comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to prove that for $\ln(n) < n $, while n>0 for the comparison test. I know its intuitive that this would be true, but I am required to actually prove it. It has occurred to me to just put e on both sides, but I didn't think that would be right. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you set $x=\ln(n)$ you have to prove $x<e^x$....

Comment: Which would follow from  the fact that $e^x$ can be written as a series expansion.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: I don't really get how someone intuitively knows something in math and is unable to prove it. If you know something in math either you have read it somewhere (with or without proof) or you have logically deduced it from the things you already. There is nothing like magically knowing something. As far deep mathematical conjectures are concerned they are backed by huge amount of theoretical/numerical evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x \in (0,1)$, then $\ln x = \int_1^x {1 \over t} dt \le 0$ and
hence $\ln x \le x$.

For $x \ge 1$ we have $\ln x = \int_1^x {1 \over t} dt \le \int_1^x dt = x-1 \le x$.

Answer (score 2):

You could show stronger result. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $\ln n < n^\varepsilon$ for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb N$.

To prove it, note that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^\varepsilon} = 0$$ (by l'Hospital, for example), so there exists $M>0$ such that $n\geq M$ implies $\frac{\ln n}{n^\varepsilon}<1$, i.e. $\ln n<n^\varepsilon$.

Example where this is useful - prove convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\ln n)^2}{n^{3/2}}.$ (Hint: $\frac{(\ln n)^2}{n^{3/2}} < \frac{1}{n^{1+1/8}}$, for all but finitely many $n$.)

Answer (score 2):

We have for $n \in \mathbb N$:

$e^n=1+n+\frac{n^2}{2!}+...>n$.

Hence (taking logarithm , observe $\ln$ is strictly increasing)

$n > \ln n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for $0<n\leq1$ we know $\ln(n)\leq 0$ , but $n$ is positive. Now take derivatives for $n\geq1$.

Alternatively, Lord Sharks comment is another straightforward way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that 
$$ f(x) = e^x - x > 0 $$ for all $x \geq 0$. (When $x < 0$, it is obvious.)

Function $f$ is strictly increasing when $x \geq 0$ since:
$$
f'(x) = e^x - 1 \geq 0, \quad \forall \, x \geq 0.
$$

Hence for all $x \geq 0$:

$$
f(x) = e^x - x \geq f(0) = e^0 - 0 = 1 > 0 \quad \Longrightarrow
\quad e^x > x
$$

Answer (score 0):

**By elementary means:**

Consider the base-$2$ logarithm, for convenience.

$$n>1\land\text{lg}(n)<n\implies 2n>1\land\text{lg}(n)+1<n+1<2n$$

and by induction and by monotonicity of $\log$ and the identity function, this holds for all $n>1$.

For larger bases, the inequality is strengthened.